# Unity - Dealing with multiple arrays and understanding loops

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, unity-game-engine, foreach

So I'm having a hard time understanding how multiple arrays and loops work. For example, in a game you have the trading functionalities and you create a method like this:

```
public void TradeItems(string[] giveItemKey, int[] giveAmount, string[] takeItemKey, int[] takeAmount)
{

}
```

You can call for the method to trade fewer items for more or vice versa. Example, you give 3 Double daggers & 4 Boots for 2 Armor.

```
TradeItems(new string[] { "Double Dagger", "Boots" }, new int[] { 3,4}, new string[] {"Armor" }, new int[] {2 });
```

So based on that method, how would you go about it? Would it be something like this?

```
public void TradeItems(string[] giveItemKey, int[] giveAmount, string[] takeItemKey, int[] takeAmount)
{
  if (HasItemsToTrade())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < giveItemKey.Length; i++)
        {
            RemoveItems(giveItemKey[i], giveAmount[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < takeItemKey.Length; i++)
        {
            AddItems(takeItemKey[i], takeAmount[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("You don't have required items to trade");
    }

}
```

Also note that the giveItemKey array and takeItemKey array could have, equal or unequal lengths etc.

I appreciate any help and knowledge i can get about these.

Comment: Are you finding a better solution for `void TradeItems()` function?

Comment: yeah like perhaps a much cleaner or easier structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would rather use a `Dictionary` instead of two separate collections of items that eventually match in sizes..

```
public void TradeItems(Dictionary<string, int> give, Dictionary<string int> take)
{
    if (HasItemsToTrade(give))
    {
        foreach(var givePair in give) 
        {
            RemoveItems(givePair.Key, givePair.Value);
        }

        foreach(var takePair in take)
        {
            AddItems(takePair.Key, takePair.Value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("You don't have required items to trade");
    }
}
```

So your `HasItmesToTrade` would probably iterate over the entries in `give` and check if they are in your inventory like e.g.

```
private bool HasItemsToTrade(Dictionary<string, int> give)
{
    foreach(var kvp in give)
    {
        if(!inventory.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)) return false;

        if(inventory[kvp.Key] < kvp.Value) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So you would rather call it like

```
TradeItems(new Dictionary<string, int> { {"Double Dagger", 3}, {"Boots", 4} }, new Dictionary<string, int>{ {"Armor", 2 } });
```

Comment: Much cleaner and simpler code for sure. gonna see if it works well with my scriptableobject items